# Format Quickbooks XML with XLST?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to format the XML data below, so it appears nicely in a browser using XSLT.  I can't seem to extract the  rows.

I've tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Quickbooks Test</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Column1</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Column2</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select='//Row[@type="Data"]'>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ColData/@value"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ColData/@value"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions for how I can extract the @value attributes from the ColData nodes, ideally in two nice columns?

Sorry if this is obvious!  I can't find it anywhere by searching...

=====
ORIGINAL XML DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Header>
    <Time>2016-04-18T12:03:32-07:00</Time>
    <ReportName>BalanceSheet</ReportName>
    <DateMacro>this fiscal year-to-date</DateMacro>
    <ReportBasis>Accrual</ReportBasis>
    <StartPeriod>2015-08-01</StartPeriod>
    <EndPeriod>2016-04-18</EndPeriod>
    <SummarizeColumnsBy>Total</SummarizeColumnsBy>
    <Currency>CAD</Currency>
    <Option>
      <Name>AccountingStandard</Name>
      <Value>IFRS</Value>
    </Option>
    <Option>
      <Name>NoReportData</Name>
      <Value>false</Value>
    </Option>
  </Header>
  <Columns>
    <Column>
      <ColTitle/>
      <ColType>Account</ColType>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>ColKey</Name>
        <Value>account</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <ColTitle>Total</ColTitle>
      <ColType>Money</ColType>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>ColKey</Name>
        <Value>total</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </Column>
  </Columns>
  <Rows>
    <Row type="Section" group="TotalAssets">
      <Header>
        <ColData value="Assets"/>
        <ColData value=""/>
      </Header>
      <Rows>
        <Row type="Section" group="OtherCurrentAssets">
          <Header>
            <ColData value="Current Assets"/>
            <ColData value=""/>
          </Header>
          <Rows>
            <Row type="Data">
              <ColData value="Undeposited Funds" id="3"/>
              <ColData value="353847.76"/>
            </Row>
            <Row type="Section" group="BankAccounts">
              <Header>
                <ColData value="Cash and cash equivalents"/>
                <ColData value=""/>
              </Header>
              <Rows>
                <Row type="Data">
                  <ColData value="Chequing" id="20"/>
                  <ColData value="-221951.44"/>
                </Row>
              </Rows>
              <Summary>
                <ColData value="Total Cash and cash equivalents"/>
                <ColData value="-221951.44"/>
              </Summary>
            </Row>
            <Row type="Section" group="AR">
              <Header>
                <ColData value="Accounts receivable (A/R)"/>
                <ColData value=""/>
              </Header>
              <Rows>
                <Row type="Data">
                  <ColData value="Accounts Receivable (A/R)" id="8"/>
                  <ColData value="29520.17"/>
                </Row>
              </Rows>
              <Summary>
                <ColData value="Total Accounts receivable (A/R)"/>
                <ColData value="29520.17"/>
              </Summary>
            </Row>
          </Rows>
          <Summary>
            <ColData value="Total Current Assets"/>
            <ColData value="161416.49"/>
          </Summary>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
      <Summary>
        <ColData value="Total Assets"/>
        <ColData value="161416.49"/>
      </Summary>
    </Row>
    <Row type="Section" group="TotalLiabilitiesAndEquity">
      <Header>
        <ColData value="Liabilities and Equity"/>
        <ColData value=""/>
      </Header>
      <Rows>
        <Row type="Section" group="OtherCurrentLiabilities">
          <Header>
            <ColData value="Current Liabilities"/>
            <ColData value=""/>
          </Header>
          <Rows>
            <Row type="Data">
              <ColData value="GST/HST Payable" id="9"/>
              <ColData value="22363.06"/>
            </Row>
            <Row type="Section">
              <Header>
                <ColData value="Payroll Liabilities" id="46"/>
                <ColData value=""/>
              </Header>
              <Rows>
                <Row type="Data">
                  <ColData value="Federal Taxes" id="47"/>
                  <ColData value="1180.75"/>
                </Row>
              </Rows>
              <Summary>
                <ColData value="Total Payroll Liabilities"/>
                <ColData value="1180.75"/>
              </Summary>
            </Row>
            <Row type="Section" group="AP">
              <Header>
                <ColData value="Accounts Payable"/>
                <ColData value=""/>
              </Header>
              <Rows>
                <Row type="Data">
                  <ColData value="Accounts Payable (A/P)" id="18"/>
                  <ColData value="-724.78"/>
                </Row>
              </Rows>
              <Summary>
                <ColData value="Total Accounts Payable"/>
                <ColData value="-724.78"/>
              </Summary>
            </Row>
          </Rows>
          <Summary>
            <ColData value="Total Current Liabilities"/>
            <ColData value="22819.03"/>
          </Summary>
        </Row>
        <Row type="Section" group="Equity">
          <Header>
            <ColData value="Equity"/>
            <ColData value=""/>
          </Header>
          <Rows>
            <Row type="Data">
              <ColData value="Retained Earnings" id="2"/>
              <ColData value="32298.57"/>
            </Row>
            <Row type="Data" group="NetIncome">
              <ColData value="Profit for the year"/>
              <ColData value="106298.89"/>
            </Row>
          </Rows>
          <Summary>
            <ColData value="Total Equity"/>
            <ColData value="138597.46"/>
          </Summary>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
      <Summary>
        <ColData value="Total Liabilities and Equity"/>
        <ColData value="161416.49"/>
      </Summary>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Your source XML places all its elements in a *namespace*; you must declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing the elements in the source XML.
2. You are selecting the same value for both cells of the row.

Try it this way instead (this assumes a data row will always have two cells):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Quickbooks Test</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Column1</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Column2</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select='//ns1:Row[@type="Data"]'>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ns1:ColData[1]/@value"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ns1:ColData[2]/@value"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's fantastic!! Thanks a million!